# Get voltage released from audio jack button

Tags: android

I want to get the voltage/pulse released from volume/pause button of an android earphone from code.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

TIA

Comment: there is no voltmeter embedded into Android device.

Comment: So we cannot read the signals/ resistance from the volume control buttons? But whenever we press volume buttons from the earphone, it actually sends some signals resistance/signal right? how can we find it

Comment: just put some volt/ampere-meter between your volume control and your device. `it actually sends some signals resistance/signal right` there is no other way to pass a signal, except this and magic.